# Can I get infected from a .torrent file?

Tags: virus, bittorrent

Is it possible to get a virus from a `.torrent` file?

I mean, I know `.exe` and other executable files can have viruses or can be malicious, but can the same be done using a `.torrent` file? Maybe writing some code in `.torrent` that causes its client software to work in unexpected ways. Just feeling paranoid ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any data file, when loaded into a vulnerable application, can be a vector for an infection.

Comment: So, thats a yes for .torrent files? A more specific answer?

Comment: True, but: is it likely?

Comment: It's a yes for *any* file. .torrent, .jpg, .html... any file.

Comment: Yes anything is possible, but I have never read of this being done, and I read way to much on security vulnerabilities every day, have for 10 years. Yes you are Paranoid. Thanks for giving the bad guys another idea. I thought Ignacio was pretty specific regarding your question.

Comment: Thanks Moab, well I guess what I wanted to say (but didn't in the question) was that whether its common to get infected that way. So turns out its not, atleast not at the moment :) And you're welcome, I'm good with ideas :P

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the application that handles your .torrent files is handling them correctly (i.e. check them for consistency, handle errors correctly, etc.) then the torrent file itself probably is not a thread for your machine. At least it's not the easiest way to infect your machine.

BUT: The torrent allows you to download other data that might be infected (and often is when you download software illegaly). So watch out what you are downloading.

Answer (score 0):

The .torrent itself is not *typically* a threat (though as Ignacio points out the *possibility* at least exists).  However, the software that processes torrent files use them to trigger a download of what it typically a much larger payload.  The contents of this payload are unverified and my understanding of bittorrent traffic is that it would not be difficult for anyone participating in a bittorrent swarm to inject malicious code into that payload.

Comment: Actually, it's extremely difficult. The file names, sizes, and order are fixed in the .torrent file, and each chunk of the torrented content itself is hashed. Getting *just* the right content at *just* the position while maintaining the hash is ludicrously hard. And if your change happens to cross a chunk boundary then you need to hope that both chunks come from clients with the change already.

Comment: @Joel, if your assumption was true, anti-p2p companies would just need to inject faulty data to corrupt the files being shared in a swarm.

Comment: @Ignacio, why would the code that validates the fragments be less prone to attacks than the code that validates the `.torrent` file?

Comment: @Jakub: They have been known to do that. What separates them from what Joel is saying is that the chunks are actually meaningless garbage instead of malicious code.

Comment: @Arjan: The fragments are fixed in size, which means that there's a lot less potential for overruns (but admittedly still not *none*). And the hash routines themselves are so old they're practically bulletproof.

Comment: @Ignacio, *valid* fragments might be fixed in size...?

Comment: @Arjan: The size of the chunks is defined in the .torrent file, and each chunk can come from multiple files in the content which requires the client to be smart at loading it, so there's no point where an invalid fragment can interfere with this.